# How to pass a generic interface as a function/method parameter in Go?

Tags: go, generics, interface, polymorphism

I am new to Go and want to know how I can pass a generic interface without a concrete type defined as a function parameter in Go.

Below is the sample code

```
type GenericInterface [T any] interface {
    Print() T
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Val string
}

func (m MyStruct) Get() string {
    return m.Val
}

func CallGenericInterface(g GenericInterface) {
    g.Print()
}


func main() {

    myStruct := MyStruct {
        Val : "Hello",
    }


    CallGenericInterface(myStruct)
}
```

When I compile the code, I get the error saying that

```
cannot use generic type GenericInterface[T any] without instantiation
```

However, I am able to make the error go away by changing the function signature for my `CallGenericInterface` function as below

```
type GenericInterface [T any] interface {
    Print() T
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Val string
}

func (m MyStruct) Get() string {
    return m.Val
}

func CallGenericInterface(g GenericInterface[any]) {
    g.Print()
}


func main() {

    myStruct := MyStruct {
        Val : "Hello",
    }


    CallGenericInterface(myStruct)
}
```

However, now the issue is that I am not able to pass myStruct to the function call and am getting the below error

```
./main.go:100:23: cannot use myStruct (variable of type MyStruct) as type GenericInterface[*any] in argument to CallGenericInterface:
        MyStruct does not implement GenericInterface[*any] (missing Print method)
```

Is there anything I am missing regarding generics in golang or concept in general ? Thanks

Comment: parametrize the caller function: `CallGenericInterface[T any](g GenericInterface[T])` then you have to actually make `MyStruct` implement the interface. https://go.dev/play/p/LXcNIjWnN5O ,